# Property or method "message" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js

** Here's The Screenshot:-**
[image]

**Here's The MessageComposer.vue:-**

```
<template>
    <div class="composer">
    <textarea v-model="message" @keydown.enter="send" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
    data() {
        return {
        messsage: ''                
            };
          },
        methods: {
            send(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (this.message == '') {
                return;
    }

    this.$emit('send', this.message);
    this.message = '';
}
}
}   

</script>


<style lang="scss" scoped>
.composer textarea {
    width: 96%;
    margin: 10px;
    resize: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    padding: 6px;
}
</style>
```

**Here's The Conversation.vue:-**

```
<template>
<div class="conversation">
    <h1>{{contact ? contact.name : 'Select a Contact'}}</h1>
    <MessageFeed :contact="contact" :messages="messages"/>
    <MessageComposer @send="sendMessage"/>




</div>
</template>

<script>
    import MessageFeed from './MessageFeed.vue';
    import MessageComposer from './MessageComposer.vue';

    export default {
        props: {
        contact: {
        type: Object,
        default: null
},
        messages: {
            type: Array,
            default: []
}
},
    methods: {
        sendMessage(text){
            if (!this.contact) {
            return;
}
        axios.post('/conversation/send', {
        contact_id: this.contact.id,
        text: text
    }).then((response) => {
        this.$emit('new', response.data);
}) 
}

},

components: {MessageFeed, MessageComposer}

}

</script>


<style lang="scss" scoped>
.conversation {
    flex: 5;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;

    h1 {
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px dashed lightgray;
    }
}
</style>
```

**Here's The ChatApp.vue:-**

```
<template>
    <div class="chat-app">
    <Conversation :contact="selectedContact" :messages="messages" @new="saveNewMessage"/>
    <ContactsList :contacts="contacts" @selected="startConversationWith"/>
     </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Conversation from './Conversation.vue';
    import ContactsList from './ContactsList.vue';
    export default {
    props: {
    user:{
        type: Object,
        required: true
}
},
        data() {
            return{
        selectedContact: null,
        messages: [],
        contacts: []
};

        },
    mounted() {

        axios.get('/contacts')
              .then((response) => {

        this.contacts = response.data;      
});

},
   methods: {
    startConversationWith(contact){
    axios.get(`/conversation/${contact.id}`)
        .then((response) => {
            this.message = response.data;
            this.selectedContact = contact;
})
},
    saveNewMessage(text){
        this.messages.push(text);
}
},
    components: {Conversation, ContactsList}

    }
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.chat-app {
    display: flex;
}
</style>
```

I can't seem to find any error or mistake in the codes,
The mistake must probably be really silly (sorry for that).

I've been stuck on this since yesterday,
I hope this info is enough to resolve this error

I was just following a Tutorial, Please Help

*-ThankYou*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **MessageComposer.vue**, the return data

```
return {
    messsage: ''  // spelling error. Should be message
},
```

Comment: Anyways Thanks For The Help

Comment: yess i just realized that, i am able to hit enter and send the message but at the same time "request failed status code 500" appears ill create a new question -thanks